# Apenas permite 5 tentativas na duplicação de chave o EntityFrameWork? a 6 cracha no SaveChange()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, vb.net, entity-framework-6, concorrência

Na duplicação de chave na gravação com EntityFrameWork em concorrência com muitos utilizadores apenas permite 5 tentativas e na 6 cracha no SaveChange() (exemplo 1).

Se for com SqlConnection não dá qualquer problema (exemplo 2).

Exemplo 1:

```
Public Sub AdicionaAux(ByRef Tentativas As Integer)
        Dim inBlnRepete As Boolean = False
        Try
            Using ctx As New BD.Dinamica.Aplicacao
                Using trans As DbContextTransaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
                    Try
                        Dim t As tbArtigos = ctx.tbArtigos.FirstOrDefault
                        ctx.tbArtigos.Attach(t)
                        ctx.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Added
                        ctx.SaveChanges()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        trans.Rollback()
                        Throw
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch
            inBlnRepete = True 'RepeteFuncaoPorConcorrencia(ex, Tentativas)
            If inBlnRepete And Tentativas < 5 Then
                AdicionaAux(Tentativas)
            Else
                Throw
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Exemplo 2:

```
 Public Sub AdicionaAux(ByRef Tentativas As Integer)
        Try
            Dim appServidorSQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServidorSQL")
            Dim appInstanciaSQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("InstanciaSQL")
            Dim appBDEmpresa As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BDEmpresa")
            Using connection As New SqlConnection("Server=" & appServidorSQL & "\" & appInstanciaSQL & ";User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=" & appBDEmpresa & ";")
                connection.Open()
                Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
                Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction")
                command.Connection = connection
                command.Transaction = transaction
                Try
                    command.CommandText = _
                      "Insert into tbDestinos (Codigo, Descricao, Ativo, Sistema, DataCriacao, UtilizadorCriacao) VALUES ('POR', 'Description',1,1,getdate(),'xxx')"
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    transaction.Commit()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    transaction.Rollback()
                    Throw
                End Try
            End Using
        Catch
            AdicionaAux(Tentativas)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução está aqui:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758469/Implementing-Connection-Resiliency-with-Entity-Fra

```
public class PharylonExecutionStrategy : DbExecutionStrategy
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The default retry limit is 5, which means that the total amount of time spent 
        /// between retries is 26 seconds plus the random factor.
        /// </summary>
        public PharylonExecutionStrategy()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of "PharylonExecutionStrategy" with the specified limits for
        /// number of retries and the delay between retries.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="maxRetryCount"> The maximum number of retry attempts. </param>
        /// <param name="maxDelay"> The maximum delay in milliseconds between retries. </param>
        public PharylonExecutionStrategy(int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxDelay)
            : base(maxRetryCount, maxDelay)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception ex)
        {
            bool retry = false;

            SqlException sqlException = ex as SqlException;
            if (sqlException != null)
            {
                int[] errorsToRetry =
                {
                    1205,  //Deadlock
                    -2,    //Timeout
                    2601  //primary key violation. Normally you wouldn't want to retry these, 
                          //but some procs in my database can cause it, because it's a crappy 
                          //legacy junkpile.
                };
                if (sqlException.Errors.Cast<SqlError>().Any(x => errorsToRetry.Contains(x.Number)))
                {
                    retry = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add some error logging on this line for errors we aren't retrying.
                    //Make sure you record the Number property of sqlError. 
                    //If you see an error pop up that you want to retry, you can look in 
                    //your log and add that number to the list above.
                }
            }
            if (ex is TimeoutException)
            {
                retry = true;
            }
            return retry;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas a função ShouldRetryOn na aceita blocos com Transaction.

Comment: A solução passa por usar Estratégia de execução de chamada manual. exemplo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/data/dn307226, no entanto ainda não consegui colocar a trabalhar.

Answer (score 0):

A abertura do escopo transacional está errada. Você náo abre o escopo a partir da conexão ao banco de dados: abre a partir do próprio .NET, porque o manejo de objetos não é puramente uma questão do banco de dados.

O correto seria algo assim:

```vb
Public Sub AdicionaAux(ByRef Tentativas As Integer)
    Dim inBlnRepete As Boolean = False
    Try
        Using ctx As New BD.Dinamica.Aplicacao
            'Mude aqui
            Using trans As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)
                'Não use Try com contexto. Intercepte exceções nos eventos OnException 
                'do Controller ou SaveChanges e SaveChangesAsync do contexto.
                'Try
                Dim t As tbArtigos = ctx.tbArtigos.FirstOrDefault
                'Não entendi por que você está selecionando o registro e fazendo Attach nele.
                'Apenas a seleção já faz o registro ser observado, então estou comentando esta linha.
                'ctx.tbArtigos.Attach(t)
                ctx.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Added
                ctx.SaveChanges()
                trans.Complete()
                'Catch ex As Exception
                '    trans.Rollback()
                '    Throw
                'End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    'Considere retirar este Catch também
    Catch
        inBlnRepete = True 'RepeteFuncaoPorConcorrencia(ex, Tentativas)
        If inBlnRepete And Tentativas < 5 Then
            AdicionaAux(Tentativas)
        Else
            Throw
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

O Entity Framework não é um ORM 100% dedicado a SQL, ou a um tipo de tecnologia relacional que envolva SQL: é um *framework* agnóstico. Além disso, o suporte a *multithreading* não é seguro nativamente: é preciso um esforço extra do programador para as regiões críticas.

Comment: Em primeiro de tudo muito obrigado pela resposta. Retirei o try, coloquei o TransactionScope sem ser Async e as tentativas coloquei no controller, no entanto ao fim das 5 tentativas o visual studio bloqueia. Isto parece só acontecer com os erros de IX do SQL de chaves únicas, que é o caso que preciso. Pois podem estar vários utilizadores com o mesmo nº a gravar e assim nas tentativas incrementava o nº para +1.

Comment: Agora que vi que esqueci de completar o *scope*. Experimente testar novamente.

Comment: Consegui colocar a funcionar sem try nenhum e com o OnException, mas chega a 6 tentativa falha, cracha na mesma. Não será alguma parametrização do dbcontext?

Comment: Não entendi o tipo de teste que você está fazendo. Poderia dar um exemplo editando sua pergunta? Em teoria, apenas isso já faz o código funcionar da maneira correta.

Comment: Achei outro problema no seu código. Você não seleciona o registro e faz um `Attach` dele logo em seguida. O contexto já observa o registro, então o `Attach` é inútil e problemático naquele ponto.